# Emacs 24 builtin cedet function highlight

Tags: emacs, cedet

I want to get rid of the underline above functions,
e.g., as shown in this screenshot above "void":

http://cedet.sourceforge.net/img-gen/semantic-ia-complete-menu.png

I cannot find anything obvious in the documentation,
but heck, I don't even know what to search for in the first place.
("function marker", "underline", ...)

I set up cedet like this:

```
;; cedet
(require 'semantic)
(require 'semantic/sb)
(require 'srecode)
(global-ede-mode 1)
(semantic-mode 1)
(global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)
(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
(global-semantic-idle-completions-mode 1)
(global-semantic-decoration-mode 1)
(global-semantic-highlight-func-mode 1)
(global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode -1)
(global-semantic-idle-summary-mode 1)
(global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode 1)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode)
(set-default 'semantic-case-fold t)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by the semantic-decoration-mode, so either disable it completely or just modify the face for tag boundaries. For finding out which face you have to modify, move to the position and do

C-u C-x =

and look at the face overlays (this should be semantic-tag-boundary-face). You can then customize it by clicking on it or via

M-x customize-face RET semantic-tag-boundary-face RET

Answer (score 4):

This should be `semantic-highlight-func-current-tag-face`... You can also check other `semantic-....` faces