# emacs cedet (semantic) how to remove hyphenate function decoration

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038114/emacs-24-builtin-cedet-function-highlight), I was able to remove some of the ugly underlining semantic utilizes with it's inline parsing, but I still have a hyphen appearing at each of my function calls (and sometimes else where) that I would really like to remove. How can I do this? I have also looked through http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/semantic.html#Tag-Decoration-Mode.

Reference image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at your CEDET config instead.
You're probably calling `semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers`.
And this function got its name for a reason.
So instead of enabling a function that has *excessive* it its name,
and then trying to remove the excessive features, why not just stick with the basics?
Just to show you my CEDET setup:

```
(load "~/git/cedet/cedet-devel-load")
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file
             "~/Software/deal.II/include/deal.II/base/config.h")
(semantic-add-system-include "~/Software/deal.II/include/" 'c++-mode)
(set-default 'semantic-case-fold t)
(semantic-mode 1)
```

But if there some extra cool functionality that
only `semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers` provides, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the hyphen was part of the semantic tag folding mode, which functions to collapse and expand code blocks in the gui version of emacs. I am not sure the same functionality is achieved in the terminal interface; but regardless, to remove these hyphens from my code, all I had to do was turn off

```
(global-semantic-tag-folding-mode)
```